# Facebook logged me in to my second account with my first account credentials

Tags: facebook, login

I have 2 Facebook account, each have different email and password, I was logged in to Facebook using my first account, but then I decided to reset my Google Chrome setting, and when I back to Facebook, I was logged out, so I try to login again, and accidentally clicked and logged in to my second account because of the browser save password feature, so I log out from my second account, and put my first account credentials to login.

But then Facebook logged me in to second account instead of first account, I got confused, I logged out and try to login again with first account, but Facebook still logged me in to my second account, so I was thinking this might be a bug , so I logged out, login using my second account credentials, Facebook logged me in to my second account, and then I log out, then I tied to login to my first account with my first account credentials.

But Facebook logged me in to my second account again. Then I tried to log out, reset Chrome setting again, disabled browser save password feature, cleared Facebook cache, and try to login to first account again, but again Facebook logged me in to my second account instead of my first account.

Can anyone help me or at least give me idea how to solve this problem please? I don't know anymore what I should do to solve this, searched the internet but none worked. I tried to ask question in Facebook help center, but the website was broken, I was able to write question there but when I clicked the post button, it do nothing, tried several time and refreshed the website and cleared cache and try to post the question again but the post button still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like browser problem.

Here are some possible solutions:

- Clean the browser by clearing all history from beginning
- Reset the password of your first account
- Login your first account with new password
- Do not save credentials in browser

Follow the above steps for second account in different browser:

- Open a different browser
- Reset your second account password
- Login to your second account with new password
- Do not save credentials in browser

Now, logout your any account from any browser and try to login another account.

Comment: sorry for late reply, and thanks for helping , today i turn on my pc and try to login again and the problem disappear , i didn't do anything the problem disappear by itself , i don't know how it's fixed so i probably just mark this answer .